# Finding the private key for this signature scheme

Tags: signature, keys, attack

Assume the signature scheme where $x$ is the private key and the public key $y = g^x \pmod{p}$. The signature works as:

- Choose $h \in \{0, \dots, p-2 \}$ s.t.: $\mathcal{H}(m) + x + h \equiv 0 \pmod{p-1}$, $\mathcal{H}(m)$ collision-resistant hash function.
- The signature is the triple $(m, (x+h) \pmod{p-1},g^h \pmod{p}) = (m,a,b)$
- Verification checks if:
  \begin{align}
  yb &\equiv g^a \pmod{p} \tag{1} \\
  g^{\mathcal{H}(m)}yb &\equiv 1 \pmod{p} \tag{2}
  \end{align}

The objective is to achieve and forge signatures for arbitrary messages of our choice.

Comment: Would you mind adding how the signature verification procedure works? And confirm that the goal of the exercise is finding $x$, rather than merely forging signatures?

Comment: @fgrieu I added the verification. The actual question is if total break is possible, but I assumed that is equivalent to having the private key.

Comment: "Total break" means ability, from public key and some example messages+signatures, to produce a signature accepted by the verification procedure for any message. Recovering the private key implies total break, but the converse does not hold.

Comment: Oh I see, so for total break it suffices to find a way to sign messages of your choice without knowing the private key?

Comment: Yes. The signature does not even need to be identical to one that could be produced by a normal signature process. The proof is the pudding: does the verifier accept it? Hint: what about tweaking a signature for a known message so that it becomes accepted for another arbitrary message?

Comment: @fgrieu is the triple $(m', a' , b')$ with $a' = -H(m') \pmod{p-1}$ and $b' = g^{-H(m')} \cdot y^{-1} \pmod{p}$ valid for forging signatures with $m'$ arbitrary?

Comment: Perfect! You do not even need a message/signature pair. Suggestion: write an answer.

Comment: As other have answered, the first two members in the tuple doesn't even have anything to do with the key and , anyone can calculate it even knowing the public key just from the message. Last one is equal to y<sup>-1</sup>g<sup>-H(m)</sup> modulo p, as h is just [-H(m)-x] mod (p-1)

Answer (score 1):

Let $m'$ be an arbitrary message. Then, the triple $(m', a', b')$ with:

\begin{align}
a' &= -\mathcal{H}(m') \pmod{p-1} \\
b' &= g^{-\mathcal{H}(m')} \cdot y^{-1} \pmod{p}
\end{align}

is a valid signature on $m'$. Since we forged a signature on an arbitrary message, we've achieved total break for this scheme.